# How to use new Initialization Schemes in DifferentialEquations.jl?

Tags: julia, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

I am trying to use the new Initialization Schemes option of DifferentialEquations.jl

https://diffeq.sciml.ai/dev/solvers/dae_solve/#Initialization-Schemes-1

But I do not know how to access the new methods.

```
using DifferentialEquations
import DifferentialEquations: ShampineCollocationInit
using Sundials
using Plots

function f(out,du,u,p,t)
  out[1] = - 0.04u[1]              + 1e4*u[2]*u[3] - du[1]
  out[2] = + 0.04u[1] - 3e7*u[2]^2 - 1e4*u[2]*u[3] - du[2]
  out[3] = u[1] + u[2] + u[3] - 1.0
end

u₀ = [1.0, 0, 0]
du₀ = [-0.04, 0.04, 0.0]
tspan = (0.0,100000.0)

differential_vars = [true,true,false]
prob = DAEProblem(f,du₀,u₀,tspan,differential_vars=differential_vars)

sol = solve(prob,IDA(initializealg = ShampineCollocationInit))

plot(sol, xscale=:log10, tspan=(1e-6, 1e5), layout=(3,1))
```

The previous example return the following Error:

```
WARNING: could not import DifferentialEquations.ShampineCollocationInit into Main
LoadError: UndefVarError: ShampineCollocationInit not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /home/Documents/test.jl:19
in expression starting at /home/Documents/test.jl:19
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: They don't apply to external methods like `IDA` since those internally use their own initialization methods. They apply to the Julia-based methods (are documented under the OrdinaryDiffEq.jl section) and are done like `sol = solve(prob,DABDF2(),initializealg=initializealg = ShampineCollocationInit())`. More docs are coming soon since this is brand new.

Comment: Thanks! I tried sol = solve(prob,DABDF2(),initializealg = ShampineCollocationInit()) but I still get the Error:
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: ShampineCollocationInit not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /home/anna/Documents/MASTER_ARBEIT/test.jl:18
in expression starting at /home/anna/Documents/MASTER_ARBEIT/test.jl:18

My DifferentialEquations version is: v"6.11.0"

Comment: IIRC that was a feature of the v6.12 release. You may need to update.

Comment: Is the missing multiplication sign in 0.04u[1] in out[1], out[2] critical or valid grammar?

Comment: @LutzLehmann the missing multiplication sign is fine!

Answer (score 0):

Those initialization schemes only apply to the OrdinaryDiffEq algorithms, while the initialization of IDA (Sundials.jl) is defined in the [Sundials.jl portion of the documentation](https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/solvers/dae_solve/#Sundials.jl) this may change in the near future (with a deprecation warning of course) as it gets more and more homogenized.